# Error in handlers$add(handler, key, tail) : Key / already in use with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I try to build a shiny app. I wanted to start from scratch, therefore starting very basic. Now when I'm trying to run my app, at first it seems to work, but instantly the app freezes and this error appears:

```
Error in handlers$add(handler, key, tail) : Key / already in use
```

I thought that I did sth wrong, therefore tried it with an example from the shiny tutorial. But again, the same error.

Here are my files:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),

  sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel("sidebar panel"),
  mainPanel("Data")
)
))
```

**server.R**

```
setwd("/home/User")
library(shiny)

shinyServer(
function(input, output) {
})
```

With `runApp("ws")` I get the error.

Any help is appreciated, thx.

Comment: I ran this: `runApp(list(ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(titlePanel("Test"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel("sidebar panel"),mainPanel("Data") ))), server= shinyServer(function(input, output) {})))` using `shiny_0.10.0 ` without such error. Are you sure this is sufficient to reproduce the error?

Comment: I guess it should be sufficient, because the error occurs with the posted code. I run your code and that works, but I can't find my error since the code is virtually the same. Well, obviously not...

Comment: this is a directory error. check your directories please. setwd("/home/User") seems to be giving the error

Comment: @pops I guess you are right. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
`setwd("/home/User/Test")` and than afterwards `runApp("/home/User/Test/ws")` which still gives me that error. In another App, I run it the same way, but it works. Do you have an idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got your directories mixed up. If you run `runApp()` in a separate R file where you include the directory that would fix your problem, as you just have to specify the name of the folder containing `ui.r` and `server.r`. To follow on your example below:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("sidebar panel"),
    mainPanel("Data")
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
```

Now those two are in the folder *Test*. Create another R file that only has the `runApp()` function in it. This is handy if you want to run your shiny app from a separate file (or you can force it to use a port of your choosing), giving you more control.

**Your Run file (you can call it whatever you want)**

```
library(shiny)
setwd("C:/Users")
runApp("Test")
```

Here I saved the `server.R` and the `ui.R` in one folder *Test*, then I specified what directory that folder is in and ran the program, just by specifying the name of your shiny app.

Comment: Thank you for solving my mess. :)