# how to deploy shiny app that uses local data

Tags: r, csv, dataset, local, shiny

I'm deploying my shiny app and I don't know how to input my a local dataset. I keep getting `Error: object "data" not found`. Here is my path to shiny folder.

```
library(shinyapps)
shinyapps::deployApp('C:\\Users\\Jeremy\\Desktop\\jerm2')
```

In this directory (jerm2), I have 3 things: `ui.R`, `server.R`, and my local dataset, a .csv called `proj.csv`.

In the `server.R` file, 
I set `data<-read.csv("proj.csv")`

I just don't know how to get Shiny to pick up my datasets.

Comment: take a look at here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738720/error-in-handlersaddhandler-key-tail-key-already-in-use-with-shiny/25741620#25741620

Comment: This is covered in the [Shiny tutorial lesson 5](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/).

Comment: For small datasets, you can just ``dput`` your data and paste it directly inside the ``server.r`` file. Saves the hassle of keeping track of attached files.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may want to add a subdirectory in your shiny folder called "Data" and put proj.csv there.

Then, in your `server.r` put:

```
data<-read.csv("./Data/proj.csv")
```

That will make it clear where the data is when the app is deployed to the ShinyApps service.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem. It turned out that I did not have my working directory pointing to my shiny app *at the time I used shiny.io to save and deploy my app*.

Be sure that if you're loading the data that the code reflects that your shiny app is the working directory.

Otherwise you will get a log error that looks something like this

> cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/Joseph/Documents/data/data.rda', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to write the csv under a sub folder (i.e. data/) of the shiny app directory and then added `data<-read.csv("/Data/proj.csv")` in `server.r` (as indicated in the answer). I didn't put the dot and it works.

Another thing is, when you publish it, don't forget to publish both the shiny app and the file in the shiny app folder.